# Clone only part of 3 TB disk for rescue

Tags: data-recovery

I have a 3TB RAID disk [single partition] I formatted as ext4, but I realized I needed a file on the disk and have not written any files to disk so far.

- I ran `photo-rec` twice, and while it finds the files, they are not entirely restored
- Any thoughts on using scalpel 2.0 on the cloned part?

How can I clone the sectors containing the target data so I don't always have to scan 3TB?

Comment: Did you also try `testdisk` or just `photo-rec`?

Comment: What is photo-rec? I only know Photorec.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clone your used sectors, because your formatting operation erased that information or made it unavailable to you.

And even if you could, how would you steer Photorec then to only operate on certain ranges?
There is no use in running Photorec twice.
If your file system was fragmented Photorec cannot work well.

Try out any other commercial solution, they may incorporate more information out of the remains of your old file system than Photorec. Photorec only does fingerprinting which is really good for armageddon destruction situations.